# How to get chained data from hive query?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have tableA:

```
id  colA colB(Chained)
1   11   17
2   22   41
3   44   42
4   82   43
5   17   13
6   20   85
7   26   90
8   13   19
9   19   82
```

I want result set of chained data like below from hive query:

```
id  ChainedCol(from colA)   colB
1   11                      17
5   17                      13
8   13                      19
9   19                      82
4   82                      43
```

Comment: What do you mean by "chained"?  How are you describing the result set?

Comment: 11 is linked with 17, then 17 is linked with 13 and so on. I want results which are chained or linked.

Answer (score 0):

I used a common table expression and do a join to itself based on colA and colB. Then use union to remove duplicates.

```
with tmp as
(  select a.id id_a, a.colA colA_a, a.colB colB_a, b.id id_b, b.colA colA_b, b.colB colB_b
  from tbl a
  join tbl b
  on a.colA=b.colB 
)
select id_b id,colA_b colA,colB_b colB
from tmp
union
select id_a,colA_a,colB_a
from tmp;
```

Comment: Here I also want to filter out rest chains with are not linked with Id=1 , eg 1 is linked with 11 , then only 1 id’s chain will be accepted.

Comment: please check first if my answer is acceptable or not. Then create another SO for your new question.